# Putting natural language into sentence logic

Tags: formalisation

I’ve been practicing expressing natural language sentences into sentence logic. However, I need help transcribing these following four sentences into  sentence logic (along with an accurate transcription guide):

**1.** *Keith is old, but Mick is older.*

**2.** *She’s either a wanton, or she’s a virgin, but she cannot be both!*

**3.** *The airplane has departed, and either you will succeed, or the world will implode (or both!).*

**4.** *Either the airplane has departed and you will succeed, or the airplane has departed and the the world will implode (or both!).*

The addition of “both” in the last three examples throw me off a bit. Also, for examples 3 and 4, would they or would they not be logically equivalent under the distribute law?

I’m thinking that example 2 is just (X v Y), if she’s a wanton = X, and she’s a virgin = Y.

Comment: "but" is "and".

Comment: for 2, you have to add the parte "not both". **v** in classical sentential logic is not exclusive.

Comment: In 3 you can use **v**, because we have "(or both)".

Comment: See Kleene, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=q-YEuuZ_j8EC&pg=PA63), page 63.

Answer (score 1):

1: AND. The contrast denoted by "*but*" has no relevance because Mick's oldness does not negate Keith's.

2: *exclusive or* (denoted by XOR). The premise "*she cannot be both*" rules out the OR connector.

3: (airplane departed)AND(you will succeed OR world will implode). Removing the term "*or both*" would require usage of XOR instead of OR.

Yes, #4 is equivalent to #3 (distributive law).

Comment: So for 1–if P = Keith is old, and Q = Mick is older—it would just be P ∧ Q? Should the transcription of Q be “Mick is older than Keith”?